# What's the difference between sass and scss commands in the terminal

Tags: sass

After I installing Sass ruby gem, three new commands have been added into the system: `sass`, `scss` and `sass-convert`. So, my question is what the difference between `sass` and `scss` commands is, do they share the same functionality? Because both of them can turn .sass file or .scss file into .css file:

`$ sass style.sass style.css`
`$ sass style.scss style.css`
`$ scss style.sass style.css`
`$ scss style.scss style.css`

All this four kinds of directives can run correctly.

PS: I'm NOT asking the differences between SCSS syntax and Sass syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `--help` flag on your command would have given you your answer:

sass-convert:

```
$ sass-convert --help
Usage: sass-convert [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]

Description:
  Converts between CSS, Sass, and SCSS files.
  E.g. converts from SCSS to Sass,
  or converts from CSS to SCSS (adding appropriate nesting).
```

scss:

```
$ scss --help
Usage: scss [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]

Description:
  Converts SCSS or Sass files to CSS.
```

sass:

```
$ sass --help
Usage: sass [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]

Description:
  Converts SCSS or Sass files to CSS.
```

Comment: Yeah, I'v done the same thing before. I'm just wondering does this mean `sass` command and `scss` command are the same under the hood?

Comment: @houhr Since SCSS is a superset of CSS3 and SASS is not. I believe that those commands aren't the same under the hood even though they are supposed to output the same CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The command `scss` is equivalent to `sass --scss`, where the command `sass` is equivalent to `scss --sass`. These two commands (a.k.a. the two options) use different *default syntax* for [syntax selection](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax_selection).

At first, both `scss` and `sass` would parse your syntax based on your file extension. (`scss` would use the sass syntax parser if your file extension is sass, and vice versa.) They would behave the same in this case and that's why you get the correct result.

However, if your file doesn't have a file extension. The command would parse the syntax using the *default syntax*. For example, the following code would give you correct result because it uses sass syntax parser.

```
$ scss style.sass style.css
```

The following code would probably give you a parsing error because it uses scss syntax parser.

```
$ scss style_sass.txt style.css
```

Answer (score -2):

Sass is a CSS pre-processor with syntax advancements. Style sheets in the advanced syntax are processed by the program, and turned into regular CSS style sheets. However, they do not extend the CSS standard itself.

The main reason for this is the addition of features that CSS painfully lacks (like variables).

Re the difference between SCSS and Sass, the text on the [Sass home page](http://sass-lang.com/) should answer the question:

`Sass is an extension of CSS3, adding nested rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. It’s translated to well-formatted, standard CSS using the command line tool or a web-framework plugin.`

`Sass has two syntaxes. The new main syntax (as of Sass 3) is known as “SCSS” (for “Sassy CSS”), and is a superset of CSS3’s syntax. This means that every valid CSS3 stylesheet is valid SCSS as well. SCSS files use the extension .scss.`

`The second, older syntax is known as the indented syntax (or just “Sass”). Inspired by Haml’s terseness, it’s intended for people who prefer conciseness over similarity to CSS. Instead of brackets and semicolons, it uses the indentation of lines to specify blocks. Although no longer the primary syntax, the indented syntax will continue to be supported. Files in the indented syntax use the extension .sass.`

However, all this works only with the Sass pre-compiler which in the end creates CSS. It is not an extension to the CSS standard itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not asking the differences between SCSS syntax and Sass syntax, I'm asking the differences between `sass` command and `scss` command in the terminal.